# Is it okay to plug a surge protector strip into a surge suppressing power outlet?

Tags: electrical, home-theater, surge-suppression

I just bought a house that has one of [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-Gang-Recessed-TV-Media-Box-Kit-with-Surge-Suppressing-Outlet-and-Low-Voltage-Inserts-White-TV1WTVSSW/304271154) where the TV would go. I do not want to change things or do any re-wiring.

It only has two ports. I have 4 devices:

- A roku
- TV
- Soundbar
- Samsung SmartThings hub

My thought was to use a normal surge protecting power strip and plug it into this wall outlet. But, since this wall outlet is surge suppressing, I am not sure if I should. Is it dangerous to do so?

https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-Gang-Recessed-TV-Media-Box-Kit-with-Surge-Suppressing-Outlet-and-Low-Voltage-Inserts-White-TV1WTVSSW/304271154

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "don't put a surge protector on a surge protector" rule is not about the surge protection, it is about overloading circuits and tripping over wires - which really doesn't apply here. I would treat the installed receptacles as "ordinary" and use a surge protector (of known quality) to add more receptacles.